# Print specific div gives blank page on print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm getting an issue with my print div syntax

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="cetak_temuan" data-toggle="dropdown"><i style="color:white"  class="fa fa-print"></i> Cetak</button>
<div class="mod">     
<table width="100%" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="5" ><h3 align="center">INSPEKTORAT PROVINSI MALUKU</h3>
         </td> 
     </tr>
      <tr>   
         <td width="15%">Nama SKPD</td>
         <td width="2%" align="center">:</td>
         <td width="50%" id="skpd_table"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Judul Laporan</td>
          <td align="center">:</td>
          <td id="jlaporan_table"></td>
          <td width="20%">Periode Laporan</td>
          <td width="2%" align="center">:</td>
          <td width="40%" id="prlp_table"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Nomor Laporan</td>
          <td align="center">:</td>
          <td id="nolaporan_table"></td>
          <td width="20%">Periode Tindak Lanjut</td>
          <td width="2%" align="center">:</td>
          <td width="40%" id="prtl_table"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="5"><h4 align="center">URAIAN TEMUAN TINDAK LANJUT</h4></td>
      </tr>
      </table> 

      <table class="table table-borderless table-striped" >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">Kondisi</th>
              <th colspan="2">Penyebab</th>
              <th colspan="2">Rekomendasi</th>
              <th colspan="2">Tindak lanjut</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="kondisi_tabel">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#cetak_temuan').on('click', function() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
// Add handlers to be called when dfd is resolved
dfd.done(PrintElem2('.mod'));dfd;
 });

  function PrintElem2(elem){
  Popup2($(elem).html());
}

function Popup2(data) 
{
      var mywindow = window.open('','Print A Page ','height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print">@page{size:landscape;}</style><html><head><title>Cetak Lapora</title>');
    mywindow.document.write(' <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><style type="text/css" > table tr td {font-size:12px;}table > thead > tr >th , table> tbody > tr > td {font-size:10px}  #dontprint{display:none} .dontshow{display:display} </style><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);   
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    //mywindow.print();
  mywindow.document.close();
  myDelay = setInterval(checkReadyState2,10);

  function checkReadyState2(){
    if(mywindow.document.readyState == "complete") {
      clearInterval(myDelay);
      mywindow.focus();
      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();
    }
  }
    return true;
}
```

Whenever I tried my code, it's just give me a blank page on print preview. I tried using `chrome`. I tried another web browser like `Opera` and it worked as I expected but when I closed the print preview window that has been pop out, the page is unavailable to click nor to type word. What's wrong with my syntax?

or could someone suggest me another way to print a specific div using javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this. Its more simple. I have tried this code on **WINDOWS PLATFORM**, using **CHROME BROWSER** and it works like charm.

```
$(function () {
    $('#cetak_temuan').click(function () {
        var contents = $(".mod").html();
        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print">@page{size:landscape;}</style><html><head><title>Cetak Lapora</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">');
        frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" > table tr td {font-size:12px;}table > thead > tr >th , table> tbody > tr > td {font-size:10px}  #dontprint{display:none} .dontshow{display:display} </style>');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this on ipad?  Or iOS in general?  Nothing appears on page when trying code similar to this.

Comment: If you have a chance to test on iOS and come up with a solution, please let me know :)  I’m having the most trouble with it.

Comment: I've got a question that was already started about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904197/print-content-in-div-script-not-working-on-ipad

Comment: @UnitedProDesign i'd love to test that, but i have no other platform but windows... :'(

Comment: and it looks like i wouldnt have any ios in the near future :'

Comment: You really should diversify yourself :) haha, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems one problematic sentence in your code is:

```
mywindow.document.write(' <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">');
```

May be `base_url` is not defined or `bootstrap.css` is not available at derived path. You should try running your code after removing that particular line in code, if it works then you should inspect the code in that line.

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using? Maybe compatibility of `base_url()`. That's why I have suggested if your code works without sentence related with `bootstrap` then you need to inspect that line of code.

Comment: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)