# Print content in div script not working on iPad

Tags: javascript

I’ve got a piece of JavaScript code that prints the content located inside a specific div( `#printthis` ).  It works great on PC; however, when I try to use it on an ipad, the page is blank except for the “footer” that contains the page name, date, time, and how many pages.  The footer is set via the print driver/iPad.

**Any way to modify this code to work on both PC and ipad?  I haven’t tested on any other devices yet.  These are just the devices I use regularly.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printdata(title) {
    var thistitle = title;
   var contents = $("#printthis").html();
        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title><?php if(isset($title)) { echo strtoupper($title) .' '; } ?>LIST PRICE</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 500);
}

    </script>
```

I call this function via `<a onclick="printdata()" href="javascript:void(0)">Print</a>`

Comment: Any update on this?  Anyone know of a way?

Comment: can you please share your html code ? the div that you wanted to print

Comment: I cant really do that because its populated from a database.  I wish I could :(

Comment: ajax callback ?

Comment: No its a php file calling mysqli data.  Then there is the button to print contents inside that div.